# Operator overloading fail with operator [] and operator cast to int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-overloading

The following program won't compile on VS 2013 SP3. What is the problem and how can I avoid this?

```
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    operator int()      const   
    { 
        return 42; 
    }
    inline Test *operator[](const std::string &name)
    {
        return this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test ts;
    Test *k = ts["huhu"];
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
C2666: number overloads have similar conversions

Comment: Thanks dlf for spotting the duplicate.

Comment: Implicit conversions are sneaky things and should usually be avoided unless you mean the two types to be mostly interchangeable.  And if your type is meant to be interchangeable with a number, what are you doing indexing a number?

Comment: @aschepler: Minimal examples of a problem often appear to do very silly things.

Comment: @aschepler As Ben Voigt pointed out, it is only a small example to show the problem, no sense implied :-)

Comment: I realize that, but still thought the question might raise a point worth considering about the design of the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is correct.  There are two interpretations of this code:

1. The user-defined operator[], and string conversion

   ```
   ts.operator[](std::string("huhu"))
   ```
2. The built-in operator[], and int conversion

   ```
   *(int(ts) + "huhu")
   ```

Both of these require one user-defined conversion, so they are both just as "good".

To fix it, do as Yochai said, give it a `operator[]` overload that needs only a standard array-to-pointer conversion:

```
inline Test *operator[](const char* name)
{
    return operator[](std::string(name));
}
```